# unit test fails even though the code works

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

The unit test for testing the login controller fails, even though the code works.
I need to test if the status code 500 is written if access to the database fails.
I have used sinon package to mock the functionality of findOne mongoose.

**Test code:**

```
describe("Auth Controller - Login", function () {
    it("should throw an error with code 500 if accessing the database fails", function (done) {
        sinon.stub(User, "findOne");
        User.findOne.throws();

        const req = {
            body: {
                email: "test@test.com",
                password: "test123",
            },
        };

        authController
            .postLogin(req, {}, () => {})
            .then((result) => {
                expect(result).to.be.an("error");
                expect(result).to.have.property("httpStatusCode", 500);
                done();
            });

        User.findOne.restore();
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
exports.postLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ error: errors.array()[0].msg });
    }

    User.findOne({ email: email })
        .then((user) => {
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(401).json({ error: "User does not exist!" });
            }
            bcrypt
                .compare(password, user.password)
                .then((doMatch) => {
                    if (doMatch) {
                        const token = jwt.sign(
                            { email: email, userId: user._id },
                            process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
                            {
                                expiresIn: "3d",
                            }
                        );
                        return res.status(200).json({
                            token: token,
                            userId: user._id.toString(),
                            email: email,
                        });
                    }
                    return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid Password!" });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    throw new Error(err);
                });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            const error = new Error(err);
            error.httpStatusCode = 500;
            next(error);
            return error;
        });
};
```

As the findOne throws error (trigged by sinon), the catch block should return an error with 500 code. But running this test fails.

```
1 failing

  1) Auth Controller - Login
       should throw an error with code 500 if accessing the database fails:
     Error
   Error
      at Object.fake.exceptionCreator (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/default-behaviors.js:24:20)
      at Object.invoke (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/behavior.js:165:35)
      at Function.functionStub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js:42:43)
      at Function.invoke (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/proxy-invoke.js:50:47)
      at Function.findOne (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/proxy.js:285:26)
      at Object.exports.postLogin (controllers/auth.js:68:7)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/auth-controller.js:19:5)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need connect you database using before hook like this:

```
before(async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(databaseUrl);
});
```

and clean up your database and disconnect it using after hook:

```
after( async () => {
  await mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

I suggest you to not use done in your test and instead use async-await
because you are using async-await you don't need to use the done method anymore and you save yourself from a lot unnecessary complexities.

Comment: I don't need to connect to db as im already mocking findOne function using sinon. The function just mocks findOne with a sample user.

Comment: Can you upload your code on Replit so we can test it and see what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know the course you are taking, i faced with same problem. You should change the controller codes from .then() concept to async/await concept in the async/await section. Then this problem will be resolved.